# Jenkins creating wrong folder for the new jobs that were copied from other existing jobs

Tags: jenkins

Sorry, for the confusing title. I am totally new to Jenkins and have been handed over Jenkins to maintain which was set-up by someone else.

This is Jenkins Master slave config. I have 1 Master and 3 Slaves.

When I create a new job by "copying an existing" job, the new job works fine and no issues.

**QUESTION:** I see that in Jenkins workspace, this new job is creating a folder with the name of the original job that it was copied from. Why it is not creating a folder with the name of the new job instead?

Now, this is certainly not a show stopper for me, but it seems that Jenkins is creating a folder in workspace for each job that is run. And hence this particular folder is causing some confusion (although notional it is).

Hence, could you help me find out why the new job is creating a workspace folder with the name of original job it was copied from.

BTW, above issue was seen on the Jenkins slave.

Comment: I have encountered the same issue. Copy source job does not have a hard coded or otherwise manually set path to workspace.

Comment: I have the same issue in one of my downstream jobs; but not in another.  Both downstream jobs behave correctly when ran manually (not triggered by the upstream job). I don't have anything hardcoded and my scripts are relying on the $JOB_NAME

Answer (score 2):

It can be solved by configuring the correct building workspace in jenkins job.

General > Advanced > custom workspace > "give your correct workspace"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem:

- copied some jenkins project and wondered about hard coded workspace paths

Console output of the copied project. Job failed due to missing D: drive.

```
12:30:44 java.io.IOException: Failed to mkdirs: D:\TEAMS\WORKSPACE\RELEASE_1_1
```

The problem i had: the 'Advanced project options' were not expanded and the configure GUI had an enormous width, that i didn´t see the button to expand and show the 'advanced' settings.

In fact (thanks to sti): the original project had some hard coded workspace path.

Comment: are you sitting in the same company as mine :D ? I have the same problem just 3 hours ago and your answer solve my problem :D

Comment: i´m not sure 8D ! But very nice that it solved your problem! Nevertheless i ran into the next one ;)

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is that you accidentally triggered the wrong job. You could change the job to print the directory where it executes by adding something like:

```
echo "XXX $JOB_NAME running in directory $WORKSPACE"
```

into the build step script. Then look for XXX in the build console log.

Second possibility is that you found an old workspace of the original job. Jenkins leaves workspaces lying around just in case it needs them again so it does not have to make them from scratch.

Third possibility is the original job is configured to use a hard-coded path as workspace. (Custom workspace). If you clone such a job, it would be a good idea to change the hard-coded path. An even better idea would be to let Jenkins manage the workspace and it's naming.

And finally, if all the other possibilities have been checked, you may have found a bug. You could look for it in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/ and create a bug report if it is a new one.